# How to get text from a JTextfield and use it as an int

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, calculator, parseint

I have all of this in one file.  I am trying to get the int from the text field jtfNumber1 and jtfNumber2 and then display the result of the action based on which button is pressed into into jtfResult.  I have the buttons working.  They currently display a test message.  I am stuck with getting the string from the textfield.

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame {

    // Create Buttons and fields
    private JButton jbtAdd = new JButton("Add");
    private JButton jbtSub = new JButton("Subtract");
    private JButton jbtMul = new JButton("Multiply");
    private JButton jbtDiv = new JButton("Divide");
    private JTextField jtfNumber1 = new JTextField(8);
    private JTextField jtfNumber2 = new JTextField(8);
    private JTextField jtfResponse = new JTextField(8);

    public Calculator() {
        //Create Panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Number 1"));
        panel.add(jtfNumber1);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Number 2"));
        panel.add(jtfNumber2);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Result"));
        panel.add(jtfResponse);
        panel.add(jbtAdd);
        panel.add(jbtSub);
        panel.add(jbtMul);
        panel.add(jbtDiv);
        add(panel);
        BtnListener listener = new BtnListener();
        jbtAdd.addActionListener(listener);
        jbtSub.addActionListener(listener);
        jbtMul.addActionListener(listener);
        jbtDiv.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    class JtfListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int x = Intenger.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());
        }
    }

    class BtnListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == jbtAdd) {
                System.out.println("Test Test Test");
            } else if (e.getSource() == jbtSub) {
                System.out.println("Test Test Test");
            } else if (e.getSource() == jbtMul) {
                System.out.println("Test Test Test");
            } else if (e.getSource() == jbtDiv) {
                System.out.println("Test Test Test");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Calculator();
        frame.setTitle("Calculator");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "stuck with getting the string from the textfield" explain ?

Comment: And if you vant the value of text field then you can try Integer.valueOf(nameOfTextField)

Comment: Please have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478124/1057230), it will add something more to your knowledge, regarding using [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost done, a few changes in `actionPerformed` method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int int1 = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber2.getText());
    if (e.getSource() == jbtAdd) {
        jtfResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1+int2));
    } else if (e.getSource() == jbtSub) {
        jtfResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1-int2));
    } else if (e.getSource() == jbtMul) {
        jtfResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1*int2));
    } else if (e.getSource() == jbtDiv) {
        jtfResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1/int2));
    }
}
```

You can directly implement `ActionListner` to your class

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

and overwrite `actionPerformed` method. Also your main method should be like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //AWT event dispatching thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new Calculator();
            frame.setTitle("Calculator");
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

See **[Why SwingUtilities invokelater is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551542/swingutilities-invokelater-why-is-it-neded)**

Comment: Thanks so much!!!!!  Not sure why I keep trying to make things harder than they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());
```

if you want to use the text field's value as an integer.

Maybe this could help you: [How to Retrieve value from JTextField in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrive-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 1):

In your actionlistener you need to get the text and convert it to an Integer

***example.***

```
if (e.getSource() == jbtAdd) {
            int first = 0;
            int second = 0;
            if (jtfNumber1.getText() != null && !jtfNumber1.getText().equals("")) {
                first = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());
            }
            if (jtfNumber2.getText() != null && !jtfNumber2.getText().equals("")) {
                second = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber2.getText());
            }
            int result = first + second;
            jtfResponse.setText("" + result);

            System.out.println("Test Test Test");
        }
```

Vice-versa for remaining inputs.

Comment: Then would it be acceptable to to have the get for jtfNumber2 there as well and then try to display it in jtfResult all in the same if?

Comment: Yes.You would need to do that too.

Comment: I have updated to show you donig sum .