# Dispose Method of JavaFX Controls

Tags: java, javafx

I have a control that should react to some kinds of events, and therefore adds itself to a listener list in the constructor. Of course it should remove itself as well, but while Swing and RCP have `dispose()` methods, I can't seem to find any in JavaFx.

```
public class MyTable extends TableView implements MyListener {

public MyTable () {
    Events.addListener(this);
}

public disposeOrSomething() {
    Events.removeListener(this);
}

// actual implementation of MyListener 

}
```

Don't get hung up on the static `Events` class, thought. It does not matter to me if the control adds itself to something static or not. What is important: there are two parts of an application that are not connected except for a general event system. So when the listening part vanishes (e.g. the window gets closed) of course the listener should be disposed.

Up until know, when the listener was directly connected to the life cycle of the control, the control registered it. But now in JavaFX that won't work, and due to loosely coupled FXML files I can't see anyone else who has the necessary information (the control and the "window close event") either.

So what is a good way to clean up after controls when they are no longer used?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no built-in `dispose()` (or equivalent) method in JavaFX

Comment: In Swing, what "dispose"-method are you referring to?

Comment: @Puce I don't see how that adds to the question, but all the windows have a `dispose()` method.

Comment: Please elaborate what this static method Events.addListener does.

Comment: Consider using `WeakListener`s, e.g. a [`WeakChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WeakChangeListener.html). That way the listener will not prevent garbage collection of your object. This design just feels wrong, though.

Comment: @Puce I added the info.

Comment: @SteffiS. I would strongly advise not using a global event bus. Anyway, I can give you a workaround if you provide the signature of `MyListener` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before, I recommend not using a global event bus and, as suggested by @Puce, not registering listeners on anything else than encapsulated objects.

Anyway, here is a way to automatically subscribe to events only when a certain `Node` is showing (i.e. automatically unsubscribe when the node is removed from the scene or the window is closed). This solution makes use of ReactFX, namely the helper [EventStream#conditionOnShowing](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M4u1/org/reactfx/EventStream.html#conditionOnShowing-javafx.scene.Node-) method.

Since you didn't provide the signature of `MyListener`, I will assume this signature:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyListener {
    void handle(MyEvent event);
}
```

---

```
import org.reactfx.EventStream;
import org.reactfx.EventStreamBase;
import org.reactfx.Subscription;

public class MyTable extends TableView {
    public MyTable () {

        // Since you are using some custom event dispatching mechanism,
        // the first step is to convert that into a ReactFX EventStream.
        EventStream<MyEvent> events = new EventStreamBase<MyEvent>() {
            @Override protected Subscription observeInputs() {
                MyListener l = event -> notifyObservers(event);
                Events.addListener(l);
                return () -> Events.removeListener(l);
            }
        };

        // Now the interesting part: events will not be observed whenever
        // this MyTable is not part of a showing Window.
        events.conditionOnShowing(this).subscribe(event -> this.handleEvent(Event));
    }

    private void handleEvent(MyEvent) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: `I recommend not using a global event bus` - Why?

Comment: @RobertHarvey because it makes it hard to reason about the data flow.

Comment: That's still a bit vague.  If you're going to make a sweeping statement like that, it's nice if you add some tangible justifications.

Comment: See points 3. and 4. in my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646747/eventbus-pubsub-vs-reactive-extensions-rx-with-respect-to-code-clarity-in-a-si/25024898#25024898)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use the Mediator pattern and only listen to events of own child controls.

Comment: That does not work if there are two separate parts of an application that need to communicate.

Comment: `I recommend to use the Mediator pattern and only listen to events of own child controls` -- Why?