# Switch case with DialogTitleButton

Tags: java, android, button, switch-statement

Is it possible to use a Dialogtitle-button with switchcase or something else to turn on/off the visibility of a framelayout?

Or should I use any other method? I just want to use that button as a switch, when press it makes the framelayout visible and once again it will become invisible and so forth..

For the first press:

```
timerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

For the second press:

```
timerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just reverse the current status:

```
timerLayout.setVisibility(!timerLayout.isVisible());
```

But you should be aware that SWING is not thread save, therefore you should use invokeLater (See: [SwingUtilities.invokeLater() why is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551542/swingutilities-invokelater-why-is-it-needed))

So your final code could look something like this:

```
yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                timerLayout.setVisibility(!timerLayout.isVisible());
            }
        });
    }
});
```