# how to change jlabel text/color at runtime in swing aplicaiton

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I am working on project where I am doing three task on a button click which takes aprox. 2-3 mins I am changing jLabel's text using below code

```
lblStatus.setText( "Phase1 done successfully !!!, Phase2 started " );
```

but I get only "All phase done successfully !!!" text in jLabel after all run is completed.

Comment: Show us the code. Post an SSSCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your long running task in the EDT, the UI freezes until your task is done. Therefore you should do the long running task in a background thread. Within the background thread you can use `SwingUtilties.invokeLater()`to update the UI.
Example:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    lblStatus.setText( "Phase1 done successfully !!!, Phase2 started " );
}});
```

For more information see [SwingUtilities.invokeLater() why is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551542/swingutilities-invokelater-why-is-it-needed)

Comment: hi @Stefan Thank you, I was looking for alternative for thread but I think I won't chnage any think on UI at run time without Multi-threading

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is because your tasks will be executed by default by the `Event Dispatch Thread` which is responsible for managing all your Swing components as they are not thread-safe. This thread should only execute **short tasks** otherwise your application will become unresponsive. You should convert your tasks into a sub class of [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), then you will be able to use a `PropertyChangeListener` in order to modify the text of your status whenever the progress of your task evolves.

More details about [**Concurrency in `Swing`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Plus one for being the only correct answer submitted so far in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the Color using this :

```
lblStatus.setForeground(Color.red);
```

and for changing text you can use `setText()` method , if you have problem with using that send all of the code here

Answer (score 0):

to change color part text use html

```
lblStatus.setText("<html><b><font color='red'>Phase1 done successfully !!!</font></b>, Phase2 started");
```