# Components not appearing in ContentPane

Tags: java, swing, components, containers, jlabel

In my application I have a list of 6 `Jlabels`, which are added to the `contentPane` in a `for` loop. After that I add 2 `JButtons` - one for removing all the labels and the second one for adding them again:

```
public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 960, 620);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(30, 30, 30));


        LinkedList<JLabel> labels = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
            labels.get(i).setSize(280, 50);
            labels.setBackground(new Color(75, 75, 75));
            labels.setOpaque(true);
        }

        Button buttonAdd = new JButton("Add");
        buttonAdd.setBounds(310, 15, 150, 50);
        buttonAdd.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public final void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
                    labels.get(i).setLocation(15, 15+50*i);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(labels.get(i));
                }
            }
        });

        Button buttonRemove = new JButton("Remove");
        buttonRemove.setBounds(310, 15, 150, 50);
        buttonRemove.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public final void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
                    frame.getContentPane().remove(labels.get(i));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I added the 6 labels outside of linsteners they were properly added to the `ContentPane` and displayed. Yet, when I try to do this via the buttons, upon clicking the `buttonAdd` nothing happens. They do not get displayed.

I tried messing with the hierarchy, setting the indices manually but nothing worked. I suspect the MouseListeners but I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: Is the listener working? Does it print something to the console using sysout? Try this: https://alvinalexander.com/java/jbutton-listener-pressed-actionlistener

Comment: Yes, I have tried printing out something like `System.out.println("foo");` and it did show `foo` in the console.

Comment: But you called 'remove' instead of 'add' :D didn't saw this first.

Comment: little typo, it still doesn't work though :(

Comment: Try calling the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate() function after adding the components

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) What do the 6 labels represent? It's likely there is a better approach to this, but impossible to know what, without more details.

Comment: (1-) 1) The code you posted doesn't compile. Post actual code that you are testing. We don't have time to guess what you really are testing. 2) You should be adding an `ActionListener` to the button, not a MouseListener.

Answer (score 1):

First things first;

-Anything modifies the GUI has to be done in **Event Dispatch Thread(EDT).** You can read more why it is needed from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551542/swingutilities-invokelater-why-is-it-needed)

---

You have to call:

```
 Test.this.frame.revalidate();
 Test.this.frame.repaint();
```

Like below:

```
           for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
           {
              final JLabel l = labels.get( i );
                              l.setLocation( 15, 15 + (50 * i) );
              Test.this.frame.getContentPane().add( l );
           }
           Test.this.frame.revalidate();
           Test.this.frame.repaint();
```

Asides this I see in your code you use `Button` instead of `JButton`, I am assuming it is just a typing mistake. It should be `JButton`. Also

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
    labels.get(i).setSize(280, 50);
    labels.setBackground(new Color(75, 75, 75));
    labels.setOpaque(true);
    }
```

this piece of code is just wrong, labels is a `list` not a `JLabel`. Define local variable

```
JLabel labelToAdd = labels.get(i)
labelToAdd.setSize(280, 50);
labelToAdd.setBackground(new Color(75, 75, 75));
labelToAdd.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: `Anything modifies the GUI has to be done in Event Dispatch Thread(EDT).` - correct, but code executed from within a listener does execute on the EDT, so there is no need to use the invokeLater().